# fetching newest conversation from message archive openfire using smack

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire, smack

Hello guys, I'm using these lines of code to fetch list of conversation using smack

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

    final ArrayList<UsersData> users 
        = UsersManager.getInstance().getUsers();

    int count = 0;
    while(count < users.size()) {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            final String jid 
                = users.get(count).getUserJID();

            IQ iq = new IQ() {

                @Override
                public String getChildElementXML() {
                    String list = "<list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'"+
                            "with='"+jid+"'>"+
                            "<set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>"+
                            "<max>30</max></set></list>";
                    return list;
                }
            };

            iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
            iq.setPacketID(jid+System.currentTimeMillis());

            service.getXmppConnection().sendPacket(iq);
            Log.v("XmppAsyncHistory", "IQ List sent!");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        count++;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I've added my iq provider.

```
        provider.addIQProvider("list", "urn:xmpp:archive", new ListIQProvider());
```

And I get this stanza for reply.

```
D/SMACK(11130): 10:34:30 PM RCV  (1096010080): 
<iq type="result" 
id="24@suitmedia1375112070174" 
to="17@suitmedia/Smack"><list xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive">
chat with="24@suitmedia" 
 start="2013-07-25T09:57:04.121Z"/>
<chat with="24@suitmedia"  
 start="2013-07-25T11:08:28.997Z"/>
<chat with="24@suitmedia" 
 start="2013-07-29T09:29:18.295Z"/>
<chat with="24@suitmedia" 
 start="2013-07-29T07:47:29.841Z"/>
<set  xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm">
<first index="0">184</first><last>216</last>
<count>4</count></set></list></iq>
```

As you can see, it returns not the newest conversation, instead the oldest one from 25/07 to 29/07 respectively

What I want to ask is what do these tags means? 184216
And how can I get conversation list order by recent time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should add an attribute "end" to your "list" element with current time. The XML will look like:

```
<iq type='get' xmlns='jabber:client'><list xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive' end='2014-05-28T08:48:56+08:00' with='somebody@somesite'><set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'><max>10</max><before/></set></list></iq>
```